# How to open .py script within python session in PowerShell (newbie)?

Tags: python, windows, powershell

I am new to python and try some simple codes using PowerShell.
I can start python by just typing py and then do codes line for line.

```
PS C:\Users\...\python> py
[Python starts]
>>> [I can type my code. everything is fine.]
```

When I try a bit more 'complex' code it is easier to write it in a .py file and run it from PowerShell, which also works fine. However, only when python is not running, i.e., I am simply within my home directory.

```
PS C:\Users\...\python> py game1.py
[desired output]
PS C:\Users\...\python>
```

The script runs fine and I get all the output, but I don't know how
to access values, classes, functions, output, etc. from the session.

Now here is my really stupid question: Can I run a .py file within a Python session in PowerShell?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's a [tutorial](http://newcoder.io/begin/setup-your-machine/#windows) that describes how to do that (along with a number of other things).

Comment: You cannot access the python classes/etc unless you manage to parse the output from powershell or return everything from the python script in a way powershell can interpret.  When you launch `py game1.py` you are launching a python session, but it's contained to itself, not shared with powershell.

Comment: `py -i game1.py` will drop into the Python shell after the script is finished.

Comment: BTW, you're not running Python "in" PowerShell, but "from" PowerShell, from which py.exe inherits the console handle (a connection to a console that's hosted by an instance of conhost.exe) and console input/screen handles for its standard I/O (stdin, stdout, stderr). In turn py.exe finds and executes an installed python.exe, which inherits the console and standard I/O handles from py.exe. The console is a shared resource, but usually only 1 process is actively using it, while ancestor processes wait.

Comment: @eryksun Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks also for the explanation.